# SQL query on how to Count the number of comments each post have

Tags: php, mysql

I have two database table called "comments" and "posts"

In the "posts" table I got post_id, post_title

In the "comments" table I got comment_id, post_id, message

The post_id in the comments table stores the id of the post that was being commented. This way I can count how many comments a post have.

I tried doing research and end up this code below:

```
$displaypost = "SELECT * FROM posts";
$result = $conn->query($displaypost);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $postid = $row['post_id'];
        $posttitle =$row['post_title'];

        $countdata = "SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM comments WHERE post_id='$postid'";
        $countresult = $conn->query($countdata);
        $countrow = mysqli_fetch_row($countresult); 
        $total_comment = $countrow[0];
        echo "Post Title: $posttitle";
        echo "Post Comment: $total_comment";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

The code above results to:

> Unable to fetch mysqli_fetch_row()

Comment: in the query you can update the line to $countdata = "SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM comments WHERE post_id="+$postid ;

Comment: result is:

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli
Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one query, replace "SELECT * FROM posts" by

```
    SELECT post_title,count(posts.post_id) as Total FROM posts JOIN comments WHERE posts.post_id = comments.post_id GROUP BY posts.post_id
```

Then you will have

```
      $posttitle = $row['post_title'];
      $total_comment =$row['Total'];

      echo "Post Title: $posttitle";
      echo "Post Comment: $total_comment";
```

Final code

```
 $displaypost = "SELECT post_title,count(posts.post_id) as Total FROM posts JOIN comments WHERE posts.post_id = comments.post_id GROUP BY posts.post_id";
 $result = $conn->query($displaypost);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $posttitle = $row['post_title'];
      $total_comment =$row['Total'];

      echo "Post Title: $posttitle";
      echo "Post Comment: $total_comment";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, let me try this, it is somewhat easy to understand

Comment: This is wow I mean wow, really wow . . Finally got it and make it work using the code you provided. Thank you so much. . Finally sorted out.

Comment: @nagatron2 ...and never execute a query inside a loop.

Comment: @Strawberry - got it, I will remember it :)

Comment: @RobertoJúnior - the code worked; however, when I added new post (10 posts) only 2 posts are being displayed. It seems that if the "comments" table is empty nothing will be display even if the "posts" table is populated.

I feel like there a condition that needs to be added somewhere in the code that will determine whether this post id is present in the comment table or not. If present it will count, if not then set to 0. Any idea? thanks

Comment: sorry to bother I figured out :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a SQL Join and Gouping clause to do this all at once

```
SELECT Posts.*,Count(Comments.*) as CommentCount FROM posts Posts LEFT JOIN comments Comments ON (Post.id = Comments.post_id) GROUP BY Post.id
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html

EDIT:

```
     $query = "SELECT Posts.*,Count(Comments.*) as CommentCount FROM posts Posts LEFT JOIN comments Comments ON (Post.id = Comments.post_id) GROUP BY Post.id";  
     $result = $conn->query($query);
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "Post ID: {$row['id']} has {$row['CommentCount']} Comment(s)! <br />";
     }
```

Comment: Do I put the query outside the while loop?

Comment: You wouldn't need to loop through all the posts to query the DB for each post to get the comment count. Just match up my query to your schema and run it through a SQL tool (IE phpMyAdmin ) and you'll see the results you have to work with ( You'll have all the columns for your posts and a new column 'CommentCount' with the number of comments) all in a single query. Cheers -J

Comment: I put some example code assuming you're using Mysqli() object.  ** fixed some formatting issues.... -J

Comment: Thank you for the idea, let me try if I can pull the idea off, the query is a bit complicated. :)

Comment: @nagatron2 it's the way to go, no need to pound the DB with queries. Glad i was able to learn ya sumthin ! :-))))

Comment: Thank you for the idea and the links, it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `WHERE post_id='$postid'";` 
It should be `"WHERE post_id=" + $postid +";";` Because your not adding the variable your just creating a long string with the variable name in it.

Comment: The result is the same as what skakon (above comment) suggest.. :(